# Can't close popup in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working with simple app showing GDP per capita using wbdata, matplotlib and kivy. I want to show a popup with simple message but I got an error after clicking the button which is supposed to close popup window. I don't know what I do wrong.
Here's part of my code:

```
class P(FloatLayout):
    pass


class MyGrid(Widget):

    country_text_input = ObjectProperty()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Events
    def plot_button_pressed(self):
        country_name = self.country_text_input.text

        try:
            country_code = search_for_country_code(country_name)

            country_data = get_country_data(country_name, country_code)

            country_data.plot_gdp_info()

        except:
            show_popup()


def show_popup():
    show = P()

    popupWindow = Popup(title="Error", content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400))

    popupWindow.open()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Building UserInterface (main application)
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
```

And the .kv file

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<MyGrid>:

    country_text_input: country_text_input

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height


        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "Country: "

            TextInput:
                id: country_text_input
                multinline: False


        GridLayout:

            cols: 1

            Button:
                text: "Show GDP per capita data"
                on_press: root.plot_button_pressed()

<P>:

    Label:
        text: "Country not found"
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}

    Button:
        text: "OK"
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.1}
        on_press: root.dismiss()
```

After clicking button i got error *AttributeError: 'P' object has no attribute 'dismiss'*

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `root` in `kv` refers to the root of the block that it is used in. See [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords). So `root.dismiss()` is trying to call the `dismiss()` method of your `P` class (which does not exist). I think you need to save a reference to the `Popup` for use later (to dismiss). You can do this by modifying your python code:

```
class MyGrid(Widget):

    country_text_input = ObjectProperty()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Events
    def plot_button_pressed(self):
        country_name = self.country_text_input.text

        try:
            country_code = search_for_country_code(country_name)

            country_data = get_country_data(country_name, country_code)

            country_data.plot_gdp_info()

        except:
            self.popup = show_popup() # save reference to the Popup


def show_popup():
    show = P()

    popupWindow = Popup(title="Error", content=show, size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,400))

    popupWindow.open()
    return popupWindow # return a reference to the Popup
```

and in your `kv`, use that reference to dismiss the `Popup`:

```
<P>:

    Label:
        text: "Country not found"
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}

    Button:
        text: "OK"
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.1}
        on_press: app.root.popup.dismiss() # uses saved Popup reference
```